# Cached and current data displayed intermittently on Graphite - Why?

Tags: graphite

Graphite intermittently displays cached (old) data and current data if I continuously update it.

Here's what I'm doing:

First I setup a graph to show the last 15 minutes, then continuously hit the "Update Graph" button on the Graphite Composer window.  When I do this, I notice some odd behavior:

1. The graph is drawn with data points going up to the current time X. **(Good)**
2. After hitting refresh several times, the graph updates to show points going up to X + 1.  **(Good)**
3. I continue to hit update and graph reverts back to the view from step 1. **(Bad)**
4. Eventually the graph updates correctly and steps forward again, showing all the data.

I found that if I set DEFAULT_CACHE_DURATION inside local_settings.py to 1, this fixes the problem.  So I know this issue is related to caching.

But I'm still confused:  Why does Graphite sometimes show me old cached data, and sometimes show me current data?  It seems like Graphite should eithe show me cached data, or current data.  It should never show me current data...then old cached data.

Feel like I'm missing something.

I'm hesitant to set the DEFAULT_CACHE_DURATION to 1, since this seems like a kludge.  Any idea how to troubleshoot this further?

Comment: do you have memcached configured as cache backend?

Comment: No memcached, it's just plain graphite out of the box.  local_settings.py does not define any MEM_CACHE_HOSTS